# Command to force user to enter password - RHEL/Centos

Tags: bash, sudo

I am trying to use `Ansible` to create a new user and set a password for this user. I want to test if the password was actually set. I figure a command that forces me to enter the user's password would be ideal.

My question is: Given I have root access, is there a command that forces me to enter the newly created user's password? Something like a `sudo` that forces a password?

Comment: `ssh newuser@localhost`?

Comment: Given that you have root access try `passwd -S newuser` to see if a password is set.

Comment: @Lambert: Password is set. But how do I verify what it has been set to??

Comment: There is no command which can reveal passwords since they are stored as a one-way hash in `/etc/shadow`. If you have set the password yourself you could use `ssh newuser@localhost` and login to test if the password you have set is working. If you want to verify if a user has changed the password from the default you have set you can check the password age field (3th field in `/etc/shadow`) or use `passwd -S newuser` and check the 3th output value. Another method is to note down the password hash (2nd field in `/etc/shadow`) and verify that with the actual value in `/etc/shadow`